# Tetris object model in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to build tetris object model using C++. I started with the first class called Piece (kinda pseudo code):

```
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece(SomeShape passedShape):shape(passedShape);
    ~Piece();
private:
    int shape[4][4];
}
```

Every piece has a shape (4x4 array representing one of all possible tetris shapes).

And there is class PieceFactory:

```
class PieceFactory
{
public:
    PieceFactory();
    ~PieceFactory();
    Piece CreatePiece() const;
private:        
    const int squarePiece[4][4]=
    {{0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 1, 0},
     {0, 1, 1, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0}};
    const int linePiece[4][4]=
    {{0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 1, 0, 0}};
}
```

I want to have a function returning piece of random shape, and I do not know what would be the smartest way to do this. My idea would be to create a list containing all the shapes (those are 4x4 arrays), generate random number, and return the element at the random generated index, that is, return the corresponding "array" (I mean pointer to it). Is there any more elegant way to do this?

```
Piece PieceFactory::CreatePiece() const
{
    int radnomNumer = generateRandom();
    return new Piece(someListContainingAllShapes[randomNumber]);
}
```

Piece would then actually copy the passed array into the new one, so that new can be edited (for example rotated) without affecting the blueprint array.

I am still having problems with object oriented modelling paradigm (although I have some experience in other languages), so any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the difference between a piece and a shape in your model?

Comment: Piece will have its shape, color, and methods like rotate etc.

Comment: Your model is kind of redundant, as you cannot have  `{{1, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 1}};`, right?

Comment: Yes, I cannot have that combination, but if I have a line as a shape, I must have 4x4 matrix so I can rotate the matrix independently of the shape. I hope I understood you correctly

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I wouldn't do this way. You are trying to  lump "shape" and "orientation" in one data structure.Not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: That's a reasonable decision. The problem is that a shape is not reducible to a 4x4 matrix. E.g. a cube would rotate along a differen relative center than a line.

Comment: Also, if shapes are immutable, you don't really need a copy of a shape in each piece. It's enough to have a pointer to a (static const) shape such that different pieces share the sane shape data.

Comment: Aha, so maybe it would be better to pass the pointer to my static const shape and introduce an orientation? Makes sense

Comment: If you want to rotate the matrix inside a piece, ask yourself: why store the offset, but not the angle of rotation? That is, instead of (offset, rotated-matrix) why not store either (offset, angle, unrotated-matrix) or just (moved-and-rotated-matrix)? Obviously in the latter case the matrix should be larger than 4×4.

Comment: true story: Dmitry Pavlovsky - one of the guys who wrote Tetris is my girlfriend's father. However, he doesn't like to talk about it. So instead I googled "tetris source code" - here is one of the many links that came up - you should find lots of inspiration here: http://pygame.org/project-Tetris+in+73+Lines-800-.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first notice that a list containing all possible shapes in your current model would have `2^16` elements. To reduce the number, you could establish some equivalence criterion, such that

```
 {{0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 0},
 {0, 1, 0, 0}}
```

and

```
  {{0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0},
 {0, 0, 0, 0},
 {1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

are the same shape (with different orientation and position). But you can easily see how this leads to some very complex and cumbersome design.

My suggestion is to first establish what kind of information you really need when shape, position, and orientation come into play. I presume this happens when you need to compute the 'collision' between the tetris piece and the current shape of the bottom. Once you break down this computation, you'll have a much better idea how to properly encode the shape information.

Regardless of how you decide to handle low-level processing,
I would probably seek for a class hierarchy factored as below.

A `Pile` data class that describes the pile of pieces on the bottom of the screen. It could be a simple bitmap.

A base `Shape` class which stores the immutable geometry of the piece and its mutable state (position, orientation); and with two virtual methods that interact with `Pile` to determine if the current position/orientation represent a collision with the bottom and update `Pile` if that happens.

```
LShape : public BaseShape {

public:
    virtual bool inCollision(const Pile&) override; // true if this piece has hit the bottom
    virtual void pileOnBottom(Pile&) override; // update the pile of pieces if the bottom was hit

}
```

In this way it is responsibility of the particular shape to handle collision properly.

The matter of generating random pieces appears rather trivial. A factory class with an extra `generateRandom()` that picks a random element in the list of registered pieces seems perfectly fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

A fundamental design question here is, whether or not [tetrominos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino) of different shape shall have different classes:

#### Your current design

In your design, the pieces are all of the same class, wich take care of the shape through an own copy of a "template" grid:

- Advantage:  huge simplicity ! There is only one implementation of rotation, collision detection, and other functions.
- Inconvenience: no shape-dependent optimization. And there can be no shape specific rules.

Shape specific rules are not an issue in standard [tetris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetris).  But it could be a limitation if you plan an advanced game evolutions in future, for example if different pieces could have different weights, different materials, and where the shape could for example influence the acceleration (speed and movement patterns or bouncing)

***Required improvement**: with a 4x4 grid, turning a bar twice in the same direction would shift the bar, which would be really annoying for the user.  I suggest an odd size, say 5x5, in order to ensure a fixed central point for rotation*

#### Alternative with shape specialization

As you have already a piece [factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html),  it would be difficult to have the different kind of pieces represented by different classes:

```
class OShape : public Piece {
    ...
};
```

But for this to work, your factory should return a pointer to a piece (or better, a `shared_ptr<Piece>`),  and your piece functions and destructor should be virtual to enjoy a polymorphic behavior.

The big advantage of this approach is that you could draw the piece directly in the grid, knowing its position and orientation and detect collision, without being forced to use a minigrid representation.

The inconvenience is however that you have many more classes, and every class requires some special thoughts.  And in addition, the shapes would be constrained by the code (i.e. you could not offer a shape editor for the user to extend the game with his own shapes.)

#### Decorator alternative

Among the many other variants between these two extremes, I'd recommend a look at the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

- a `Shape` class is used to represent the generic shapes. It is instantiated to create basic shape objects (and their grid representation based on a rotation factor between 0 and 3).
- a `Piece` class is used as decorator for the Shape, adding the position and orientation of the piece and referring to an underlying shape object.

It's not so far from your design, but it has the advantage of have a clear [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) between the management of the `Piece` and the manipulation of the `Shape`.